# Run JS code on load and on Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please see this HTML code:

```
<div class="grid">
  <h2>First</h2>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <h2>First</h2>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
```

I was able to change order of elements on page load with this code:

```
$('.grid').each(function(){
    var p = $(this).find('p'),
        h2= $(this).find('h2');
  h2.insertAfter(p);
});
```

But there is more content coming with an ajax pagination so I wrapped that inside `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){`

Problem now is my code runs only after the ajax content is loaded, I want my code to run on both page load and on ajax loaded content.

Thank you for your assistance.

https://jsfiddle.net/j0fozshv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the stuff you need to do multiple times into a function:

```
function doMyStuff() {
  $('.grid').each(function(){
    var p = $(this).find('p'),
        h2= $(this).find('h2');
    h2.insertAfter(p);
  });

  // or do what you need. it's just an example
}
```

And after that, just use your function where you need.
On document ready:

```
$(function () {
     // ... 
     doMyStuff();
});
```

If you have AJAX stuff somewhere, just call it for success callback:

```
// just an example !
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    doMyStuff();
});
```

One more example with jQuery AJAX:

```
$.get( "/get_some_data", function( data ) {
  doMyStuff();
});
```

Maybe it makes sense for that function to take some args (e.g. data that is returned from the server):

```
function doMyStuff(data) {
  // do what you need
}
```

And again for your AJAX stuff:

```
$.get( "/get_some_data", function( data ) {
  doMyStuff(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a way that would prevent me from executing the function twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method like below and call twice, one after page load and one after ajax complete.

```
// After page load 
insertDom();

function insertDom(){
  $('.grid').each(function(){
      var p = $(this).find('p'),
      h2= $(this).find('h2');
      h2.insertAfter(p);
  });
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // Do your work
    insertDom();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a way that would prevent me from executing the function twice. I guess this should also work then.