# making javascript work after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, elementor

I have ajax displaying posts (infinite scroll).

And I have a script which works prior to the ajax response but not after.

So when the new posts are loaded, the javascript is not executed in the ajax loaded posts.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.post-link-home').find('.elementor-post').each(function() {
      let link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
      $(this).wrapAll(document.createElement('a'));
      $(this).closest('a').attr('href', link);
    });
  });
});
```

Any ideas how to make this work after the ajax loaded posts?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function PostLinkHome() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.post-link-home').find('.elementor-post').each(function() {
            let link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            $(this).wrapAll(document.createElement('a'));
            $(this).closest('a').attr('href', link);
        });
    });
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        PostLinkHome();
    });
});
```

**Explanation**

1. I gave the first function executed without Ajax a name: `PostLinkHome()`
2. I then called for that same function to be executed when Ajax is loaded:

`jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() { PostLinkHome(); });`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315294/run-js-code-on-load-and-on-ajax-loaded-content)